# Qt 4.8.4 way to change the running excusable name in runtime

Tags: qt, runtime

i have Qt c++ app that on each start is checking if there is new executable update file 
and if there is it downloading it, the problem is how can i change the name of the old executble to for example : 
foo_tmp.exe
and the new executable 
to :
foo.exe 
or in runtime or on closing or on start something

Comment: What operating system(s)?

Comment: If windows, just rename the running exe

Comment: as it running ? in runtime ?

Comment: Yes, You can rename a running windows exe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162969/how-can-a-c-binary-replace-itself

Answer (score 1):

`QFile::rename` is a static method that will allow you to rename a file.

However renaming the currently running executable file will cause you issues.  As the file is in use by the operating system you will either be prevented from doing this, cause undefined behaviour or it will simply not work.  You should most likely have a launcher application that checks for updates to the main application before starting it.

Comment: - because Windows at least prevents deleting a running executable but allows renaming

Comment: Good point, I didn't realise the poster wanted to rename the running executable. I'll update my answer.

Comment: ok what is launcher application ? i use the main exe file as the starting point of the app . i dont what to start the exe with cmd or any other app/script